# Search by value in a multimap in O(log(n)) complexity

Tags: c++, time-complexity, std, multimap

How can I efficiently search for a value in a multimap with a time complexity of O(log(n))?

I have a multimap where the keys represent locations and the values represent city names.
I want to efficiently search for a specific city name in the multimap based on the given city name.

This is the data structure:

```
    std::multimap < Location, std::string, LessX > _mmapCitiesX;
```

Here is the search function that I have implemented (this is working):

```
City CitiesManager::findCity(const std::string& cityName) const
{
    auto it = std::find_if(_mmapCitiesX.begin(), _mmapCitiesX.end(),
        [&](const City& city) {
            return city.second == cityName;
        });
    if (it == _mmapCitiesX.end()) {
        throw std::runtime_error(cityName + 
            " isn't found in the city list. Please try again");
    }
    return *it; 
}
```

(City is std::pair<Location, std::string>,
and Location is a struct with x,y cords)

To reduce complexity , I attempted to use the std::equal_range, but it didn't work...

here is my attemp:

```
City CitiesManager::findCity(const std::string& cityName) const
{
    auto range = std::equal_range(_mmapCitiesX.begin(), _mmapCitiesX.end(),
        cityName, [](const City& city, const std::string& name) {
            return city.second < name;
        });
    if (range.first == range.second) {
        throw std::runtime_error(cityName +
            " isn't found in the city list. Please try again");
    }
    return *(range.first);
}
```

I get error:

> C2664 'bool CitiesManager::findCity::<lambda_1>::operator ()(const
> City &,const
> std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator> &)
> const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const _Ty' to 'const City &'

edit:
This is LessX, I need it because I want to sort the locations by x-chords, and therefore I choose to use Location as key.

```
struct LessX
{
    bool operator()(const Location& left, const Location& right) const 
    {
        return left._x < right._x;
    }
};
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: You can't. Only the keys in a a map can be searched in O(ln N). Your choice of data structure is not suitable for the requirement. If you need to search the city names, then you'll need e.g. a map where the city names are keys.

Comment: you sure? in cppreference they said:
"The number of comparisons performed is logarithmic in the distance between first and last"

Comment: `std::equal_range` requires the range to be (partially) ordered with respect to the provided predicate, but the `(multi)map` range is ordered according to its keys. So you generally violate the precondition of the function if you use it to search map values.

Comment: @DanielG `equal_range` cannot perform magic. If your data structure is not ordered by city name then log(N) complexity is not achievable.

Comment: afaik boost has a bidirectional map

Comment: [Boost MultiIndex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) might be what you are looking for

Comment: Also note that incrementing an iterator in a map is not a constant-time operation.

Comment: @molbdnilo Can you please give a reference for that, because I do not see a reason why it should not be constant time.

Comment: @gerum In the worst case, incrementation requires traversing the underlying tree from the bottom up to the root, and all the way down on the other side. Thus, it depends on the size of the map.

Comment: "keys represent locations and the values represent city names" Interesting. How would you use such a map? 'Find a city at 48.8584° N, 2.2945° E"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Even if you fix your call site, you are ignoring the preconditions of `std::equal_range`, so your program is ill-formed.

If you want to lookup by both location and name, you need a data structure that provides such a lookup. [`boost::bimap`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) or [`boost::multi_index`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) are containers that can provide that.

Comment: wow thanks, and I can still keep it ordered by keys?

Comment: Yes. bimap orders by both the left and right value, and multi_index orders by however many things you want